# understanding salesforce licensing for development and deployment

Tags: salesforce, crm

I am trying to understand the licensing issues on I would come across on Force.com for developing an application that will have its own data source and will also be pulling data from SalesForce.com via api/service. I have spent over a day researching this from various sites but most of them keep throwing up new things which don't really answer my questions and have got me more confused. IF anyone here has any insight into this that can help me understand the cost of development and maintaining a site using Force.com, so I can compare it with building an application ground up on say .Net or Java and hosting it on a different cloud provider, then please help me out. My questions are:

1. If I have 5 developers working on an application called XYZ using the Force.com platform, how many Force.Com licenses would I need to purchase for such development work and of what type should those licenses be?
2. Would I also need to buy separate SalesForce licenses if those developers need to fetch data from the SalesForce database through code written on Force.com?
3. If I already have a SalesForce license then will my access to SalesForce be suspended if I convert that license to access Force.com for doing development work?
4. Can I reuse those same licenses for the testing phase later or should I buy separate licenses for testing?
5. Once development is complete and people create accounts for themselves on my XYZ web application, will they need a salesforce login to access the salesforce related data from their company network or can they still access it without?
6. If my XYZ web application doesn't access SalesForce's data then will my XYZ web application's users still need a salesforce or Force.com license to login into XYZ?
7. If I dont use Force.com as my development platform, and I still need to access SalesForce data, how many licenses would I need to have? One per login created on my XYZ application or just one will do?

Thanks.

Comment: I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this question, but I couldn't figure out a better place where to put it. Please suggest in the comments if I should move it out to some other area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off asking this at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) (beta). Seems like quite a lot of experts there have done some cool integrations, managed packages etc or even are [ISVs](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/). so they might have more experience in the matter. They'll maybe even point you to database.com.

Or just go and talk to SF sales rep.

Also I think you don't understand that you don't simply "buy a Salesforce license". You buy licenses bound to particular production organisation (an instance if you prefer). You can't transfer them between organisations and the fact that your web app will talk to specific Salesforce instance doesn't mean you can use same license too connect to different instance. So if this is what you mean by

> I have spent over a day researching this from various sites but most
>   of them keep throwing up new things which don't really answer my
>   questions and have got me more confused.

then you'll have hard time...

I think for such question you'll need to eventually ask your lawyer, don't trust people on the internet :) Safe harbor, blah blah, don't sue me...

1. To kick off the development you don't have to pay anything. Sign up for [Developer Edition](http://www.developerforce.com/events/regular/registration.php) and hack away. (each developer can do it, you can synchronize between them using SVN etc - it's definitely enough for quick start). If you already have a "production" (for example Enterprise Edition") then I think up to 4 simultaneous logins are allowed for each active user. This counts for different channels (so for example developer who would both click through app's UI and work in Eclipse IDE counts as 2) so you can try to do some cost cutting here... But I'd recommend 5 full Salesforce licenses.
2. No, will be sufficient.
3. I don't think you can convert licenses ;) You'd simply buy licenses of different type and contact them to reduce the count of licenses of type you don't need. You can kind of convert users by assigning them license of different type (and this might lead to change of Profile). As a result you for example downgrade a full System Administrator (on Salesforce license) to say user who can see only Chatter and loses access to Accounts etc.
4. You can use same licenses. Even to say deactivate developer user accounts and use the freed licenses to create some test users.
5. Depends how many features of SF you'd want to use (in terms of data ownership, visibility etc.). You will have to provide "some" credentials of an active user in your Salesforce. So you might be fine with having just 1 "integration user" account that would see all data and then do all filtering etc on your webapp.
6. I don't understand that one so I'm going to say "no" ;) If you don't need to connect to SF and get the data - don't? Unless you have some kind of Single Sign On solution there.
7. If you need to access Salesforce from external app you need to authenticate. Username + password, Oauth,sessionId, single-sign-on... whatever the means - SF needs something to say that this user is active, he can see this data. So it kind of goes back to answer #5.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've tried talking to an SF rep, but they are reluctant to give out any information without knowing your business model and what kind of application you want to develop. I am not sure our customer would be happy sharing that information

Comment: with regards to point #6 what I meant was: if I am build a simple application where I have no need to connect to salesforce at all. Its just a simple application for a restaurant showing our latest menus, specials of the day etc. a guestbook where my existing customers can login and leave feedback or book tables... or say new customers can register on the site and create accounts for themselves where they book tables at my restaurant. In such a case would each of these users also need a salesforce account so that they can create an account on my restaurant website?

Comment: One dedicated integration user that would connect to SF behind the scenes sounds enough for such scenario. You'll need to do authentication and data filtering on your own (eg. figure out how show them only your their reservations etc) but full-blown solution (it's called "Customer Portal" and yes, it has licenses for your clients) seems a bit overkill.